# Voting Correction affect badge progress and daily limit

Tags: bug, voting-correction

Yesterday someone or something ran over 20 of my answers and upvoted them. The reputation change was later corrected by the voting correction script and I'm fine with that. However, I noticed that I did not receive reputation for normal upvotes today (because of the daily limit hit by those 20 upvotes) and I see that my badge progress still counts the upvotes which were 'reputation corrected'.

**UPD**: recalculation fixed reputation that was above the daily limit, but corrected upvotes still counted in badge progress.

Is this intentional or is it a bug?

**UPD2**: Badge progress came to normal too, although a bit later.

Comment: It looks like the system assumes you're reputation-capped for the day. I expect that to be resolved on a next full reputation re-calc. Give it another day or so.

Comment: see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857 and  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24867/90769

Comment: You can try to trigger recalculation "_In this way, one can trigger a recalculation oneself (provided one has eligible posts), deleting or undeleting a post triggers a recalculation (maybe not if the deletion/undeletion doesn't cause a reputation change), so by temporarily deleting or undeleting a post one can bring one's reputation up-to-date (it takes several minutes until the recalculation occurs, so one has to wait a bit before undoing the temporary [un]deletion)._" And give it a big hour

Comment: @Self It worked! Thank you. The badge progress didn't change though. I suppose because the upvotes are still there.